# Switch the ElementaryOS to another distribution

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot

I have dual boot Windows and ElementaryOS installed on my notebook with Core 2 duo and 3GB RAM, but I want to install another distribution instead of eOS, I think in Mint, My question is, I need to delete in windows the partition of Elementary and install mint or I can "override" elementary ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to grasp what you mean by "override" in this context. But since you already have a partition with Elementary, you don't have to do anything from Windows. The Linux Mint installer can reformat that partition for you.

There is a good guide here:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=122276

To summarize:

- Boot from the Linux Mint installation media.
- Reformat the partition with Elementary.
- Install Linux Mint on the partition that previously
  held Elementary.

Comment: OP probably meant “overwrite”.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything before installing a new operating system. The installer will let you choose where to install. You may need to pick “advanced partitioning” or some such during the installation. Once you've reached the partitioning interface, select the partition that contains elementary OS and mark it to be erased and used by Mint instead.

As a rule, don't use Windows to configure partitions for Linux. Windows's ability to cope with non-Windows partitions is very limited.